# High CPU utilizing query

Tags: sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

I have below query which is consuming high CPU on SQL Server 2017 web edition server.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IM_ID,IM_NAME, IM_ADDR_ID 
FROM MST_INSURANCE 
WHERE IM_NAME >= 'a' 
AND IM_NAME <= 'Zzzzzzz' 
AND EXISTS 
   (SELECT BLH_ID 
    FROM TRN_BILLING_HEAD, 
         TRN_BILLING_DET 
WHERE BLH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0 
AND BLH_TRNTYPE = 'BL' 
AND BLD_BLH_ID = BLH_ID 
AND BLH_CLAIM_STATUS = 'B' 
AND BLD_BOOL_DO_NOT_SEND = 0 
AND BLD_RESP_NOW <= 2 
AND ( 
      (BLD_RESP_NOW = 0 
       AND BLH_INS1_ID = IM_ID) 
    OR 
     (BLD_RESP_NOW = 1 
      AND BLH_INS2_ID = IM_ID) 
   OR 
     (BLD_RESP_NOW = 2 
      AND BLH_INS3_ID = IM_ID) 
     ) 
   ) 
 ORDER BY 2,1
```

I am aware the query structure used is an old one hence I tried to optimize the query by adding INNER JOIN in the query and removed EXISTS clause as per below. This helped to optimize the query cost but I guess I have changed the query logic.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IM_ID,IM_NAME, IM_ADDR_ID, BLH_ID FROM MST_INSURANCE AS INSU  
 INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_HEAD AS HEAD ON BLH_INS1_ID = IM_ID AND  BLH_INS2_ID = IM_ID AND BLH_INS3_ID = IM_ID
INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_DET AS DET ON BLD_BLH_ID = BLH_ID  
WHERE
IM_NAME >= 'a' AND IM_NAME <= 'Zzzzzzz' AND
BLH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0 AND BLH_TRNTYPE = 'BL'  
AND BLH_CLAIM_STATUS = 'B' AND BLD_BOOL_DO_NOT_SEND = 0 AND BLD_RESP_NOW <= 2
AND  (BLD_RESP_NOW = 0  OR BLD_RESP_NOW = 1  
OR BLD_RESP_NOW = 2) ORDER BY 2,1
```

I am not a developer hence finding it difficult to optimise the query.
Can anyone please suggest any changes in the query?

Comment: Do you *need* the `DISTINCT`? I rarely find you need it in a query like this; if you do I find it's more an indicator that the joins aren't correct. Unfortunately, as none of your columns are qualified it's impossible for us to even guess if you *might*; however, I doubt it.

Comment: Offering advice on performance problems really requires us to see the actual execution plan and the table structures, constraints and indexes. High cpu is often caused by expensive sort operations, so this is something to look out for and can be mitigated with the correct indexing. Add your actual plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan). Also note that ordering columns by ordinal position is deprecated and could be removed in a future version.

Comment: In the original query, there doesn't appear to be a join between TRN_BILLING_HEAD         TRN_BILLING_DET

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for responding me, I really appreciate it.

I have included some JOIN in the original query as per below which reduced the query cost significantly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IM_ID,IM_NAME, IM_ADDR_ID FROM MST_INSURANCE AS INSU  
INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_HEAD AS HEAD ON BLH_INS1_ID = IM_ID OR  BLH_INS2_ID = IM_ID OR BLH_INS3_ID = IM_ID
INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_DET AS DET ON BLD_BLH_ID = BLH_ID  
WHERE
IM_NAME >= 'a' AND IM_NAME <= 'Zzzzzzz' AND
BLH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0 AND BLH_TRNTYPE = 'BL'  
AND BLH_CLAIM_STATUS = 'B' AND BLD_BOOL_DO_NOT_SEND = 0 AND BLD_RESP_NOW <= 2
AND  (BLD_RESP_NOW = 0  OR BLD_RESP_NOW = 1  
OR BLD_RESP_NOW = 2) ORDER BY 2,1
```